# Blank screen after TV turns off in Xubuntu 15.10

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, hdmi, 15.10

I have a Phillips TV hooked up to my computer via HDMI.  The computer is running Xubuntu 15.10.  If the TV turns off, when I turn it back on, the screen is blank - the computer is sending no signal.  I have to manually restart the computer to get a visual again.

Prior to 15.10, when I had this issue, I could use the fix discussed here: [Xubuntu 14.04 black screen after monitor off/on](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477138/xubuntu-14-04-black-screen-after-monitor-off-on)  I have hotplug events disabled in my xorg.conf, and the optional configurations they mention I have also put in.  Light locker is completely disabled, as is all power management options.  These worked until I upgraded to 15.10 - now, even though those solutions are still in place, the issue has returned. Not sure what to do here, since everything else refers to 14.04, and those fixes are not making a difference here. :(

**UPDATE**

Here is some additional info, after trying one of the solutions below:

Output from `xrandr --current` while the screen is still on:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected 1814x1020+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm panning 1920x1080+0+0
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    29.97    24.00    23.97    60.00  
   1360x768      60.02  
   1280x768      59.99  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x480       59.94    60.05  
   640x480       59.94    59.93
```

I tried using this command to restart the display:

`xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1814x1020+2+0 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal`

by binding it to a hotkey using `xbindkeys`:

```
# Wake up the display
"xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1814x1020+2+0 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal"
control+w
```

Comment: Any solutions? I have the same issue. Have a fresh install of xubuntu 15.10 and a Samsung TV plugged into HDMI of my GT 730. No errors/infos in syslog/dmesg/Xorg log etc.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have found a "dirty" work around for this.

When having black screen do:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output VGA-0 --off
```

HDMI-0 = the output where your TV is connected
1920x1080 = The mode you want to have (desktop resolution)
VGA-0 = other outputs which should be disconnected

To find your output name and supported modes do:

```
xrandr --current
```

This will give you a list of disconnected and connected outputs and their supported modes (for those who are connected).

But this is just a work around, not a solution in my optinion

Comment: This will not work for me - the screen is black, and it is the only screen, so I cannot see a command prompt in order to type those commands. I am in need of a configuration solution.

Comment: You have multiple options to execute this command. It will work if you connected with vnc client (vnc server should be installed on the machine :P ) and from there you can enter the command or you could also assign this command as a hotkey and everytime the screen is black, press the hotkey. I know it is not a good solution, but better then rebooting :)

Comment: I could not get the command to work - my display remained off.  I updated the question with more information (too long for a comment).  Please take a look and tell me if I've done something wrong, @prdatur

Comment: Another update: the command worked when I was in a full-screen application (I was playing Portal), but does not work when the display is off.